# Getting 401 Unauthorized on getItem API from Ebay

Tags: api, rest, ebay-api

I am trying to get product details from eBay using API

for now, I am trying to it using REST API CLIENT

I have generated a Token and added in the Authorization header for specified Scope API its working fine but for [Get Item](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/resources/item/methods/getItem) it is giving `401 Unauthorized` on REST API Client and `400 Bad Request` from my web application

Need Help

[image]

Comment: Hello Mr. @Real Magento Man, have you solved the issue?

Comment: i think i have used SOAP API instead on REST

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your reply